# Cannot run Jmeter on my terminal

Tags: jmeter

When I write `jmeter` in my `terminal` I have this error.

```
An error occurred: Unable to make field private static java.lang.String sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.awtAppClassName accessible: module java.desktop does not "opens sun.awt.X11" to unnamed module @4d3167f4
```

Comment: first - how do you start jmeter ? can you start it with the jmeter with UI ?

Comment: No. I click on icon and nothing happens. In terminal I print "jmeter" and terminal give me an error

Comment: try to download one more time http://jmeter.apache.org/ jmeter, and after if it still not work try to run it as 32 bit app

Comment: Is jmeter.apache.org suitable for Ubuntu?

Comment: it runs on java - so it should be compatible with Ubuntu as well

Comment: no. it doesn't run

Comment: run `jmeter.sh` command.

Comment: command not found

Comment: try the steps here http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jmeter/1941/getting-started-with-jmeter/6345/installation-or-setup#t=201702081138477657636

Answer (score 2):

1. Download latest [Oracle JRE or JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) and unpack it somewhere, i.e. to `/opt/java` folder
2. Download latest [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) and unpack it to `/opt/jmeter` folder
3. Amend [PATH](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html) environment variable to start with the "bin" folder of Oracle JDK installation like:

   ```
   PATH=/opt/java/bin:$PATH && export PATH
   ```
4. In the same terminal window navigate to JMeter folder

   ```
   pushd /opt/jmeter
   ```
5. Execute JMeter

   ```
   ./jmeter
   ```

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue installing **openjdk-9-jre** on 
 Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

installing the "older" Version via

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

worked for me right away.

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/OpenJDK/

Comment: `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 jmeter` was needed at my side to start `jmeter` after installing the old JAVA, as at my side `java -version` gives `openjdk version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17`

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of Java you are running.  I received this same error on another java application when I started using Java 9 EA.  I downloaded jmeter just out of curiosity and get the same error.